# Warning Connecting XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I managed to connect to my XMPP server through asmack but i see a NullPointerException warning after connecting . I put the carcets.bks file in the raw folder. Is this warning important?

```
the logcat show:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:62)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:839)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:268)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:71)


   this is my connection :

    configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());
    config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port);
    config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
        config.setTruststorePassword(null);
        config.setTruststorePath(null);
    } else {
        config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
        String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                + "cacerts.bks";
        config.setTruststorePath(path);
    }
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
```

Comment: Yes. the warning is important.   The logcat should give you a file and line number where the null pointer is being detected.

Comment: i put  the logcat  above but i can't access those files

Comment: The logcat contains a stack trace.  Did you show the whole trace?  If so I would contact org.jivesoftware because the trace in your post is all their software.   If there is more to the trace and it gets to your code eventually, look at the last line in your code to be sure the arguments are valid, and the jivesoftware components have been set up properly.

Comment: i realized that if  i put config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled); the warning disappears is that the right way to solve the problem?

Comment: @josiland have you solved this problem,i am also facing these issue,in my raw folder i have ssltestcert too,same error is happening for me also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the trust store path.  Your exception occurs when the path is being looked up.

Are you hitting the first condition for the build version?  The path is set to null in that case.

Comment: the same problem arising for me,how could i solve this one,could you explain clearly